# What is the easiest way to find the number of triangles in this picture?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the easiest way to find the number of triangles in this picture?

[image]

I tried the listing method but I am not sure with my answer if it is correct. I am trying to find a better way to solve this.

My answer is 33.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that you posted three similar questions on combinatorics in quick succession. Have you attempted these problems? What have you done and where are you stuck? Problems like "here's my homework, solve it pls" are generally not well received. Please edit your questions to include this information.

Comment: Hi Ma'am @Angelica. I am practicing problems every week for recreational purposes. Those are not my homework. I want to join competitions in Math but I don't have a trainer. This is my cousin's account here. He allowed me to use it to solicit ideas from those experienced Math Guru here. I am sorry if I was not able to elaborate the questions.

Comment: Hi @bof. Thank you for your comment. May I kindly ask where did you get $8, 5, 4$, and $2$?

Comment: @bof I tried to do manual counting. I think there are some triangles that I missed counting.

Answer (score 3):

A triangle is formed by three lines intersecting at three different points. There are $8$ line segments in the picture, so at most $\binom83=56$ triangles. Since all line segments meet in the picture, the only way three of them can fail to form a triangle is if they all meet at one point. There are $\binom53=10$ concurrent triples at the bottom left corner and $\binom43=4$ concurrent triples at the bottom right corner, so the actual number of triangles in the picture is
$$\binom83-\binom53-\binom43=56-10-4=\boxed{42}.$$

Comment: Lets assume that we have similar situation. Our triangle $ABC$ has $5$ lines intersecting on $A$ , $4$  lines intersecting on $B$ , $6$  lines intersecting on $C$. Then , the answer wil be $$\binom{12}{3}-\binom{5}{3}-\binom{4}{3}-\binom{6}{3}$$ Am i right ?

Comment: @PeterPAN Yes **provided** you don't have three lines meeting at a point in the interior of the triangle.